# Update div paremeter dynamically in facebook chat plugin

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like, as a javascript newbie, update Facebook's [customer chat plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin) with some custom parameter in the `ref` field (actually cookie of the user to which I show the plugin). I cannot seem to be able to override the default that I set. Why is that? I've been stuck on this forever. I always receive the ref parameter `default_ref`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
    function updateRef(){
        console.log("updating ref");
        document.getElementById("chat").ref="update_ref";
        console.log("tried to update ref;")
    }

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'xxxxxxxx',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.0'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    console.log("customer chatloading");
    document.getElementById("chat").ref = "test_work_please";
    console.log("finished loading chat");
    console.log("ref is " + document.getElementById("chat").ref);
</script>
<body>


<div id="chat" class="fb-customerchat"
messenger_app_id="xxxxxxxxxx"
logged_in_greeting="yyyyyyy
logged_out_greeting="zzzzz"
greeting_dialog_display="fade"
ref="default_ref"
page_id="xxxxxxxxxxxx">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Because Facebook take the div when the SDK loads and replace it with the customer chat plugin. Create a new div and call https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/ on it

Comment: @WizKid sorry I dont really understand where would I put it? Something like this still does not work `FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('chat').ref="hellooo");`

Comment: You create a new div with with the right ref. Then call FB.XFBML.parse on that div

Comment: @WizKid Thanks, I tried to do it like [this](https://gist.github.com/jansila/3c461f4b95bb88dcead47cc5f2ec7ac7)   But stil received an [error](https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/plugins/customerchat.php?app_id=210090072943719&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FmAiQUwlReIP.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df27fa4ca2bb7a72%26domain%3D55c128be.ngrok.io%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F55c128be.ngrok.io%252Ff2e40b9df17a448%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=0&locale=cs_CZ&sdk=joey). about misspecified page_id. I think I am getting closer though.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you do it is impossible to help you

Comment: Just trying to put in a cookie of each user I show it to :)