# Cors error while rendering FB Chat plugin for whitelisted domains

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

I am trying to add the Messenger Live Customer Chat Plugin dynamically to a site by first whitelisting the domain via the API and then injecting the script tag to the whitelisted domain site.

Now, after injecting the script to the whitelisted site it fails with CORS error. But, if I manually whitelist the URL via the Facebook app using the UI it works fine. I dont understand why does whitelisting via API does not work when the docs clearly say it should work.

1. Successfully whitelisting a domain for a FB page via the API

```
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/me/messenger_profile?access_token=EAxxxxxxxPr' \
  -H 'authority: graph.facebook.com' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="96", "Google Chrome";v="96"' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.55 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"' \
  -H 'origin: https://livechat.frangout.com' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: cross-site' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://livechat.frangout.com/' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  --data-raw '{"whitelisted_domains":["https://my-domain.com"]}' \
  --compressed
```

Result: `{success: true }` and I can also GET the whitelisted_domains and see it is already whitelisted

2. Injecting script dynamically to the whitelisted site so that it loads the Messenger Live Chat Plugin

```
        var fbCustomerChat = document.createElement('div');
        fbCustomerChat.id = "fb-customerchat";
        fbCustomerChat.classList.add("fb-customerchat");
        fbCustomerChat.setAttribute('page_id', 'xxx')
        document.body.appendChild(fbCustomerChat);

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId            : 'xxx',
              autoLogAppEvents : true,
              xfbml            : true,
              version          : 'v12.0'
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

3. Browser Logs

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.facebook.com/plugins/customer_chat/facade_gating/?page_id=106040728582517&suppress_http_code=1' from origin 'https://sid-s-school-12f2.thinkific.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
xhr-patch.js:87 GET https://www.facebook.com/plugins/customer_chat/facade_gating/?page_id=106040728582517&suppress_http_code=1 net::ERR_FAILED 200

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.facebook.com/plugins/customer_chat/SDK/trucnated co

Refused to frame 'https://www.facebook.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://www.facebook.com".
```

Comment: I've heard there can be issues if you try to do it this way. This might be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50778194/update-div-paremeter-dynamically-in-facebook-chat-plugin . Do you get the same error if you add the `div` directly in the HTML? This might help as well https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: I dont have access to the HTML page directly. I have to add it via a script tag

Answer (score 3):

This might be a different issue. But I also encountered the '..has been blocked by CORS policy' issue for the Facebook Plugin Chat. Even if you already added the website URL in the Whitelisted domains (Advanced Messaging settings), it will still not work if your Facebook page is limited or restricted to only few countries. It needs to be available to all countries.

Hopefully someone will help this post in the future as searching for 'Facebook Chat Cors error' only points to this question.

Comment: Brilliant!!! Page Settings->Country restrictions

Comment: Oh is it? Let me check. I abandoned the whole project because of this issue.

Comment: My site haven't displayed any errorsx, but looks like Facebook changed something last days and I have same error in console as mentioned. I do not have any restrictions, I whitelisted my domiains. Is the error occur for you again?

Comment: me to now Aug 2023 the CORS appears.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue from facebook, in my case I had a `/` at the end of my whitelisted domain name, updating it fixed my issue.

Also move the Facebook chat SDK code to the top within the `body-tag`

```html
<body>
<!-- FB-CHAT-SDK-CODE -->
...

<!-- your code -->
...
</body>
```

```
OLD: https://www.example.com/
NEW: https://www.example.com
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I experienced the same thing before, after I checked thoroughly, it turns out that I entered the wrong **PAGE_ID** instead I entered the **APP_ID**.

You can try to check again on this line

```
chatbox.setAttribute("page_id", **YOUR_PAGE_ID**);
```

Answer (score -1):

By default facebook need add following code into html:

```
<!-- Messenger Chat plugin Code -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<!-- Your Chat plugin code -->
<div id="fb-customer-chat" class="fb-customerchat"></div>
```

You missed `fb-root` div and Chat plugin's `id` is `fb-customer-chat` not `fb-customerchat`